# Getting undefined in the array of strings

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code:-

```
    const mainFunction = async (message) => {
      const templateData = {};
      templateData.name = message.firstName;
      templateData.email = message.emailAddress;  
      templateData.account = message.accountType;
      console.log("message::::", message);
      const userId = message.userId;
    
      const emailAddresses = [`${message.emailAddress}`];
      console.log("emailAddresses->", emailAddresses);
}
```

**Logs:-**

```
2022-03-10T14:33:50.807+05:30

Copy
2022-03-10T09:03:50.806Z    8681ec6b-7f57-5148-bdd3-b6c8be7d2f15    INFO    message:::: 
{
    "userId": "b4c6cab0-a944-5f5e-81cd-b1dad4c0b54a",
    "emailAddress": "tom.dick9000@gmail.com",
    "notificationType": "NEW_USER_WELCOME_MESSAGE",
    "firstName": "tom",
    "lastName": "dick",
    "accountType": "BASIC"
}

2022-03-10T09:03:50.806Z 8681ec6b-7f57-5148-bdd3-b6c8be7d2f15 INFO message:::: {"userId":"b4c6cab0-a944-5f5e-81cd-b1dad4c0b54a","emailAddress":"tom.dick9000@gmail.com","notificationType":"NEW_USER_WELCOME_MESSAGE","firstName":"tom","lastName":"dick","accountType":"BASIC"}

2022-03-10T14:33:50.807+05:30   2022-03-10T09:03:50.807Z 8681ec6b-7f57-5148-bdd3-b6c8be7d2f15 INFO emailAddresses-> [ 'undefined' ]
```

The problem is the constant emailAddress is coming as undefined but the value of the emailAddress attribute is present in the object message. I want to pass the dynamic value to this array of Strings but not working at all.

Please let me know why it is coming as undefined. Thanks

Comment: Possible cause: [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/4642212). Try logging `JSON.stringify(message)` instead.

Comment: Why did you use the value of email address like `[`${message.emailAddress}`]`

Comment: And: why is that function `async`? You don't `await` anything.

Comment: @Andy, it is not a complete function. I'm using await in the preceding statements

Comment: @Tushar, I'm trying to populate the value of an array of strings dynamically here hence used this syntax